# How to use ssl everywhere except an endpoint

Tags: nginx, ssl, django, gunicorn

I have a Web site where I want all requests to be done with HTTPS except for requests to urls with paths that start with /out/.

nginx is configured as proxy to serve gunicorn/django content from http://127.0.0.1:8000.

here is the configuration i have so far , but it seems that it doesn't use ssl anywhere.

```
server {

listen 80;
listen 443 default ssl;
server_name my.website.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

root /home/ubuntu/app;
client_max_body_size 1m;
access_log /home/ubuntu/app/logs/access.log;
error_log /home/ubuntu/app/logs/error.log;

location ~ ^/(out|out/.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        break;
    }
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        break;
    }
    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
           rewrite  ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for please? Am I correct in my interpretation that you're looking for: `client->https->webserver->http->application`?

Comment: Yes client->https->webserver->http->application , and also serve /out/ only without htpps @BE77Y